# Auto renewable subscriptions without server

Tags: itunes, in-app-purchase, subscription

Inn app purchase programming guide says: "Server delivery is appropriate for subscriptions, services and content, because these products can be delivered
as data without altering your application bundle."

My question is: Is this a must? Or I can implement auto-renewable subscriptions build in product, without any server.

Thank you,
Horatiu

Answer (score 0):

If you need to transfer new data to the client:

```
you must have a server
```

If you just unlock something, that is already within your data:

```
you don't need a server
```

see [In-App Purchase Programming Guide - Built-in Product](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/APIOverview/OverviewoftheStoreKitAPI.html)